# How to tell Java Library what properties to use in Jython

Tags: java, properties, jasper-reports, jython

I have problems getting the xmldatasource sample project running with Jython.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/jython

"""
 - cd buildEnv/xmldatasource; ant javac
 - cd buildEnv/xmldatasource/build/classes; jar -cf xmldatasource.jar XmlDataSourceApp.class
 - copy buildEnv/xmldatasource/build/classes/xmldatasource.jar to deploy/lib/xmldatasource.jar
"""

import os
import sys

cwd = os.path.realpath(".")

sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/xmldatasource.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/jasperreports-5.0.0.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/ant-1.7.1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/antlr-2.7.5.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/barcode4j-2.1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-anim.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-awt-util.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-bridge.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-css.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-dom.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-ext.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-gvt.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-parser.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-script.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-svg-dom.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-svggen.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-util.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/batik-xml.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/bcel-5.2.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/castor-1.2.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/commons-javaflow-20060411.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/groovy-all-2.0.1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/hibernate3.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/iText-2.1.7.js1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/jackson-annotations-2.0.5.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/jackson-core-2.0.5.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/jackson-databind-2.0.5.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/jaxen-1.1.1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/jcommon-1.0.15.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/jpa.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/jxl-2.6.10.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/mondrian-3.1.1.12687.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/png-encoder-1.5.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/poi-3.7-20101029.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-20101029.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/rhino-1.7R3.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/saaj-api-1.3.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/serializer.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/servlet-api-2.4.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/spring-beans-2.5.5.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/spring-core-2.5.5.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/velocity-1.7-dep.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/xbean.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.0.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/xml-apis-ext.jar'])
sys.path.extend([cwd + '/lib/xml-apis.jar'])

import XmlDataSourceApp

from java import util
import java.io as javaio 
properties = util.Properties()
propertiesfis =javaio.FileInputStream("jasperreports.properties") 
properties.load(propertiesfis) 

javaObj = XmlDataSourceApp()

javaObj.fill()
```

As you see, all the dependencies should be load. When i try to call the fill() method, i receive the following error:
l

```
og4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "java.py", line 84, in ?
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRQueryExecuterUtils.getExecuterFactory(JRQueryExecuterUtils.java:114)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1082)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:667)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:126)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:464)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:249)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:155)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:678)
at XmlDataSourceApp.fill(XmlDataSourceApp.java:132)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory registered for the 'xPath' language.
```

I run this code simply with jython java.py.

I think the code isnt work but I dont know how to set the properties correctly. According to the sample project, the property must be set as the following:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory
```

But what if I use Jython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem of the java properties using PY4J instead of Jython.